# How can I define a complex-valued function's fractional power?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f(x) : \mathbb{R} \ni x \mapsto f(x) \in \mathbb{C}$
. I think the following $$
|f(x)|^{\alpha} = (f(x) \overline{f(x)})^{\alpha/2} = f(x)^{\alpha/2} \overline{f(x)}^{\alpha/2}
$$
holds for $\alpha \ge 1$. Then does the notation $f(x)^{\alpha/2}$ make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $f(x)^{\alpha/2}$ does make sense, but not for the reason you give.

The standard definition of $a^b$ in general complex numbers is, for $a\ne 0$,

$$a^b=e^{b\ln a}$$

Therefore,

$$f(x)^{\alpha/2}=e^{\alpha\ln f(x)/2}$$

at least for $f(x)\ne 0$. (For $f(x)=0$ it gets more complicated.)

**However**, with that common definition, your identity $(f(x) \overline{f(x)})^{\alpha/2} = f(x)^{\alpha/2} \overline{f(x)}^{\alpha/2}$ is *not* always true. For example, let $f(x)=-1,\ \alpha=1$. Then

$$\begin{align}
(f(x) \overline{f(x)})^{\alpha/2} &= (-1\cdot \overline{-1})^{1/2} \\
 &= (-1\cdot -1)^{1/2} \\
 &= 1^{1/2} \\
 &= e^{(\ln 1)/2} \\
 &= e^0 \\
 &= 1
\end{align}$$

but

$$\begin{align}
f(x)^{\alpha/2} \overline{f(x)}^{\alpha/2} &= (-1)^{1/2}\cdot\overline{-1}^{1/2} \\
 &= (-1)^{1/2}\cdot(-1)^{1/2} \\
 &= e^{i\pi/2}\cdot e^{i\pi/2} \\
 &= i\cdot i \\
 &= -1
\end{align}$$